# Посчитать процент числа от разницы чисел на PHP

Tags: php, математика

Помогите решить задачку посредствами PHP

$a = 1200;

$b = 2200;

$c = 1700;

Задача:

Сколько процентов занимает переменная `$с` в разнице между переменными `$a` и `$b` если разница между ними это 100%.

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = 1200;
$b = 2200;
$c = 1700;

$difference = abs($b - $a); // находим разницу между $a и $b
$percentage = ($c / $difference) * 100; // вычисляем процентное соотношение

echo "Переменная \$c занимает $percentage% от разницы между переменными \$a и \$b";
```